# htaccess for pretty url slugs

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am trying to set up a `.htaccess` file in the root of my project which will give me the ability to use pretty urls.

I have three types of page:

1. news.php
2. tournaments.php
3. rankings.php

However, in reality I want `news.php` and `view.php` in which the latter will handle which mark up to use for tournaments / rankings and news stories will be `site-name/news/the-slug-of-the-story/`

Here is what I have so far:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /the-site-name/
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /news.php [L]
RewriteRule ^news/(.*)/([0-9]+) news.php?slug=/news/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /view.php [L]
RewriteRule ^tournaments/(.*)/([0-9]+) view.php?page=/tournaments/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /view.php [L]
RewriteRule ^rankings/(.*)/([0-9]+) view.php?page=/rankings/$1 [L]
```

However, all of the links /tournaments/ /rankings/ seem to be using the news.php template and not view.php.

Is there anything I am missing?

### UPDATED: 13:44pm 20/02/2018

I have the `.htaccess` working now - this is final set up

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^news/?$ news.php?slug=/news/ [L]
RewriteRule ^news/(.*)/([0-9]*) news.php?slug=/news/$1/ [L]
RewriteRule ^rankings/?$ view.php?page=/rankings/ [L]
RewriteRule ^tournaments/?$ view.php?page=/tournaments/ [L]
</IfModule>
```

The only bug now is `/news/name-of-story/` works but without the final `/` it will break if one visits `/news/name-of-story`.

I will be surprised if this work on my digital ocean in the same way as XAMPP but I will cross that bridge when I come to it =]

### UPDATE: 13:51PM

I also added

`RewriteRule ^news/(.*) news.php?slug=/news/$1/ [L]`

to handle the lack of trailing slash

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> [L] means if the rule matches, don't process any more RewriteRules below this one.

Untested but, should be :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /the-site-name/
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^news/(.*)/([0-9]+) news.php?slug=/news/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^tournaments/(.*)/([0-9]+) view.php?page=/tournaments/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^rankings/(.*)/([0-9]+) view.php?page=/rankings/$1 [L]
```

**update :** (tested) -- NB : Added `/$2` (may not what you want, could remove it)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /the-site-name/
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^news/?$ news.php?slug=/news/ [L]
RewriteRule ^news/(.*)/?([0-9]*) news.php?slug=/news/$1/$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^rankings/?$ view.php?page=/rankings/ [L]
RewriteRule ^rankings/(.*)/([0-9]+) view.php?page=/rankings/$1/$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^tournaments/?$ view.php?page=/tournaments/ [L]
RewriteRule ^tournaments/(.*)/([0-9]+) view.php?page=/tournaments/$1/$2 [L]
```

Explanation :

```
^news/?$   # For "news" or "news/"
^news/(.*)/([0-9]+) news.php?slug=/news/$1/$2 # Added $2 for the second capture group
```

Comment: This hasn't worked `/tournaments/`, `/rankings/` and `/news/the-name-of-story/` all say "Object not found".

P.S. I am using XAMPP environment for Mac OS X

Comment: I have added all of this in and the `view.php` now works but only when I remove the `RewriteBase` and the `news/name-of-story/` doesn't work. 

Do you think XAMPP is playing a part here? The `.htaccess` looks solid.

Comment: @Shwmae Change `([0-9]+)` to `([0-9]*)` to made the number facultative.  `RewriteBase` is for you have an alias for your host.

Comment: I have updated my answer to reflect my current situation =] thank you for all your help so far!

Comment: @Shwmae Try with `news/(.*)/?([0-9]*)` :)

Comment: Yep even better! You're a legend!

Answer (score 0):

I can’t test this at the moment, but from what I can remember, these lines will cause that:

```
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /news.php [L]
```

That `.` is basically saying ‘rewrite all paths that aren’t a file or directory to news.php’.

`RewriteRule` works like so:

```
RewriteRule Pattern Substitution
```

The pattern `.` means anything and could be causing the problem.

Try taking out these lines:

```
RewriteRule . /news.php [L]
RewriteRule . /view.php [L]
RewriteRule . /view.php [L]
```