# htaccess with array parameter in $_GET

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I can't seem to pass a array within htaccess Rewriterule and Rewritecond.

My URL is

> example.com/search.php?mc=88&fc%5B%5D=Canon&fc%5B%5D=Dell&min=1&max=5000&cul%5B%5D=cyan&cul%5B%5D=red

As you can see I have the following parameters: mc, min, max, fc[] and cul[]. The last two ones are arrays.

How can I make a friendly URL for the users to see when I have one or two arrays in the link?

Here is my full htaccess file

> Options -MultiViews
>
> RewriteEngine On
>
> RewriteBase /
>
> ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
>
> #redirect from "/search.php?mc=123" to "category-123"
>
> RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /search.php?mc=([^&]+)\sHTTP [NC]
>
> RewriteRule ^ category-%1? [R=301,L,NE]
>
> RewriteRule ^category-([^./]+)/?$ ?mc=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
>
> #redirect from "/search.php?sc=123" to "brand-123"
>
> RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /search.php?sc=([^&]+)\sHTTP [NC]
>
> RewriteRule ^ brand-%1? [R=301,L,NE]
>
> RewriteRule ^brand-([^./]+)/?$ ?sc=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
>
> #redirect from "/product.php?s=ab-cd" to "ab-cd"
>
> RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /product.php?s=([^&]+)\sHTTP [NC]
>
> RewriteRule ^ %1? [R=301,L,NE]
>
> RewriteRule ^([^./]+)/?$ ?s=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
>
> #redirect from "/search.php?categorie=abc&search_string=abc" to "categorie-abc/cautare-abc"
>
> RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST}
> /search.php?categorie=([^&]+)&search_string=([^&]+)\sHTTP [NC]
>
> RewriteRule ^ categorie-%1/cautare-%2? [R=301,L,NE]
>
> RewriteRule ^categorie-([^./]+)/cautare-([^./]+)/?$
> ?categorie=$1&search_string=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
>
> #rewrite with arrays
>
> RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST}
> /search.php?mc=([^&]+)&fc[]=([^&]+)&min=([^&]+)&max=([^&]+)&cul[]=([^&]+)\sHTTP
> [NC]
>
> RewriteRule ^ /category-%1/fc[]-%2/min-%3/max-%4/cul[]-%5?
> [R=301,L,NE]
>
> RewriteRule
> ^category-([^./]+)/fc[]-([^./]+)/min-([^./]+)/max-([^./]+)/cul[]-([^./]+)/?$
> ?mc=$1&fc[]=$2&min=$3&max=$4&fc[]=$5 [L,QSA,NC]

Comment: I think you are talking about URL slugs? If so there are already answers available at [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48881830/htaccess-for-pretty-url-slugs). If you are using any framework then you mostly have to work with routes and dont necessarily have to change the htaccess file.

Comment: Hello! I'm writing code in simple PHP, not framework, and I want to pass to htaccess an array (fc[] and cul[]) and want to make from this 

search.php?mc=88&fc%5B%5D=Canon&fc%5B%5D=Dell&min=1&max=5000&cul%5B%5D=cyan&cul%5B%5D=red

to this
search.php?master-88/brand-Canon/brand-Dell/min-1/max-5000/color-cyan/color-red